# Javascript file. Failed to load Resource: 404 not found

Tags: javascript, html, flask, datepicker, python-3.4

I'm developing a website using flask and python3.4. In an html template I link a javascript file that I wrote containing functions defining datepicker properties. The line looks like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/datepicker.js"></script>
```

datepicker.js is definitely in my /static/js directory. I have another js file that I wrote containing multiselect functions, that is being found. I don't understand why my webapp is able to locate my multiselect.js file, but not my datepicker.js file. They are both in my js directory.

Anyway, I could use some help here, as I don't really understand why this is happening.

Comment: I forgot to mention, my OS is: Ubuntu 17.04 (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-83-generic x86_64)

Comment: If you inspect the page in the browser where you see the 404 error, what is the location from where it is trying to fetch this file?

Comment: http://172.30.26.36:8080/static/js/datepicker.js

Comment: try <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/datepicker.js"></script>.  You need to add "../" if you want to move up in folder hierarchy to access the files.  If you want to start from the root, ".." is not needed.

Comment: I changed the paths for both datepicker.js and multiselect.js, multiselect.js is still found, but datepicker.js is still unable to be found.

Comment: If you click the link from your previos comment, does that open your js file?

Comment: While it is weird that flask is not finding your file, I would recommend using flask's `url_for` function instead of hardcoding paths like so `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/datepicker.js') }}"></script>`. It might be helpful in determining where your flask app thinks your root directory is and where the static directory is in relation to that.

Comment: Clicking on the link takes me to a 404 not found page. I'll try using flask's function and get back to you.

Comment: That did not work. It looks in the same directory that the file should be in, and it still can't be found.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. Actually, url_for was showing that the root directory of the project was one directory outside of where I thought it was. I added that directory to the path, and it works now. Thank you for your help.